# using sfMailer and Dispatcher inside a task

Tags: php, task, symfony-1.4, mailer

I created a task in symfony 1.4, and I want to create a mailer based on the app.yml config.

this is my PHP code :

```
$config = sfConfig::get('app_mailers_mailer_a');
$this->_mymailer = new sfMailer($this->dispatcher, $config['param']);
```

when I execute the task, and vardump the `$config` variable, I get my config information (host, port, etc..).

The problem is in the second line, It stops their, without any error messages, so I think that the way I use the dispatcher (or `$config['param']`) is incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was not `$config` or `$this->dispatcher`, but the problem was that I forgot to initialize the `sfMailer`, so I added those lines before;

```
  Swift::registerAutoload();
  sfMailer::initialize();
```

Cheers ;)